# What's the purpose of asking for advice when a Pokemon learns a new move?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

In *Pokémon Scarlet Violet*, when your Pokemon learns a new move you can press <kbd>X</kbd> where you pick a move to forget and you can “ask for advice” from your Pokemon on which move to replace.

What's the purpose of this feature? Is the move just selected randomly?

Do I get a friendship boost if I follow my Pokemon's advice?

Comment: I've not used the feature enough to come to a definitive conclusion, but from what little I've observed so far, I don't think it's random. When I used it, my Sprigatito suggested it forget Scratch in favor of Quick Attack. It chose that attack over Leafage, Bite, and Magical Leaf. Considering Scratch and Quick Attack are of the same type and category, and have the same power and accuracy, it makes sense that Sprigatito would chose the move that doesn't have a special effect.

Comment: I personally think its random as far as i checked, or it either selects the least powerfullest moves. As far as i know no extra benefit is rewarded.

Comment: @Ladineko Maybe in terms of base power but it can give horrible advice. My friend's Meowscarada (a physical attacker) suggested forgetting Flower Trick for Energy Ball one of the few times either of us tried asking for a suggestion.

Comment: @Laurel Oh yes, the advise that is given is in no way purrfect (in Meowscarada's case). It is merely an extra function to help absolute beginners who have no idea which to pick to make a reasonable choice (without min-maxing)

Comment: I read a post on Reddit where it even suggested a random move instead of Splash for Hoppip. It seems random to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonScarletViolet/comments/yz3fau/the_new_ask_for_advice_looks_great_but/) and Twitter users, it's not a suggestion feature based on anything, it picks all 5 options on the screen at random and tells you to pick that one, even when the deleted move is clear superior.
It seems to highly de-prioritize status moves, even with redundant and obsolete attacking moves.

So it's probably just random.